# Add value from one data frame into another data frame in R

Tags: r

Hi I want to add rows from one dataframe to another dataframe using R.

I have one dataframe DATA1 which has some missing ID and Data2 has all the ID's I want to replace the DATA2 frequency column with DATA1 values for all the matching ID's.
and I want OUTPUT dataframe as my Output.

```
Data1
ID  frequency
1   1
2   7
3   11
5   4

DATA2
ID  frequency
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0

Output
ID  frequency
1   1
2   7
3   11
4   0
5   4
6   0
```

Comment: I would use `DATA2[match(Data1$ID, DATA2$ID), 'frequency'] <- Data1$frequency`

Comment: Along the right lines, but that will replace the values in `DATA2`, not create a new `Output`.

Comment: Does DATA2 always contain only zeroes, or can it contain other values that you may not want to replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data ID is unique, I think can use ID to be rownames.

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  freq = c(1, 7, 11, 4),
  row.names = c(1, 2, 3, 5)
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  freq = rep(0,6),
  row.names = seq(1, 6)
)
output <- data2
apply(
  matrix(rownames(data1), ncol=1),
  1,
  function(x){
    output[x, 1] <<- data1[x, 1];
    return(NULL)
  }
)
```

And the result is :

```
> output
  freq
1    1
2    7
3   11
4    0
5    4
6    0
```

Comment: @RomilGarg My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's an elegant single-line solution, but the `dplyr` way is to join the data frames by `ID` and then tidy up the output.

```
library(dplyr)
OUTPUT <- Data1 %>% 
            right_join(DATA2, by = "ID") %>%
            mutate(frequency = ifelse(is.na(frequency.x), frequency.y, frequency.x)) %>%
            select(ID, frequency)
```

Comment: No, the `ifelse` is required. It replaces `NA` values in `frequency.x` with the corresponding value from `frequency.y`. Just run the right join without the later steps and you'll see why.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a join with *data.table*.

```
library(data.table)
## set both data frames to data tables
setDT(Data1); setDT(Data2)
## copy 'Data2' to a new table 'Output' which we will assign values to
Output <- copy(Data2)
## join on 'ID' and assign by reference the relevant 'frequency' values
Output[Data1, frequency := i.frequency, on = "ID"]
Output
#    ID frequency
# 1:  1         1
# 2:  2         7
# 3:  3        11
# 4:  4         0
# 5:  5         4
# 6:  6         0
```

Original data:

```
Data1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), frequency = c(1L, 7L, 
11L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "frequency"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

Data2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, frequency = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), .Names = c("ID", "frequency"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```